# Magento - To write in a custom option in an item in cart by Name

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, cart

Today i arrive to write in a custom option of a product present in cart by option id as following:

```
$productId = 41;
$optionId = 42;

$valueId = $_SESSION['date'];

$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    if($item->getProductId() == $productId) {

        $o = $item->getOptionByCode('option_'.$optionId);
        $o->setHasQtyOptionUpdate(true);
        $o->setValue($valueId);

    }
}
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
```

I would like to set value in custom option in function of option name and not in function of id, because i need to make it generic (i will use a generic name for the custom option like "GENERICNAME", and i will write in it).

I tried following code just in order to have option name but it's not working (i d'ont arrive to display option name, nothing is displaid):

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    $_options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());

    foreach($_options["options"] as $option) {
        // Zend_debug::dump($option);

        echo $option['label'];
        echo $option['value'];
        echo $option['print_value'];
        echo $option['option_id'];
        // echo $option['option_type'];
        // echo $option['option_value'];
        // echo $option['custom_view'];

        // Pour charger l'option :

        // $_option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->load($option['option_id']);
    }
}
```

Do you know why and do you have an idea how to do?

Thanks in advance

Any idea????